# Proof of the completion of a normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

My question is precisely that of Mahmood’s in the following link: [Theorem 2.3-2 in _Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications_ by Erwine Kryszeg](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030457/theorem-2-3-2-in-introductory-functional-analysis-with-applications-by-erwine)

I believe the answer in this question with two upvotes does not provide a sufficient explanation. Using the notation of norms in the above question, I do not understand why $||\hat{x}_1+\hat{x}_2||_2 \leq ||\hat{x}_1||_2+||\hat{x}_2||_2$ still holds for arbitrary $\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2 \in \hat{X}$. As stated in the above question, Kreyszig only justifies this by claiming it can be deduced from the triangle inequality of $||\cdot||_1$ by a “limit process”. I am trying to make sense of what this “limit process” is.

I think Kreyszig means that the following holds (using the notation of $(\hat{X}, \hat{d})$ like in the above question):

$$||\hat{x}_1+\hat{x}_2||_2 = \hat{d}(\hat{0},\hat{x}_1+ \hat{x}_2)=_{?}  \lim_{n \to \infty} \hat{d} (\hat{0},\hat{y}^{(1)}_n+ \hat{y}^{(2)}_n)$$$$ \leq_{(1)} \lim_{n\to \infty} \Bigl(\hat{d} (\hat{0},\hat{y}^{(1)}_n)+ \hat{d} (\hat{0},\hat{y}^{(2)}_n)\Bigr) =_{(2)} \hat{d} (\hat{0}, \hat{x}_1)+ \hat{d} (\hat{0}, \hat{x}_2) = ||\hat{x}_1||_2+||\hat{x}_2||_2$$

where $(\hat{y}^{(1)}_n) \to \hat{x}_1$ and $(\hat{y}^{(2)}_n) \to \hat{x}_2$ are sequences in $W$, both existing thanks to the fact that $\bar{W}=\hat{X}$. To clarify, step $(1)$ is because it was established that the triangle inequality holds for when all the elements involved are in $W$, and $(2)$ follows from using the triangle inequality for $\hat{d}$.

**So, my question is:** Why would my step above labeled “?” be justified? I am having trouble proving this without the triangle inequality for $||\cdot||_2$ already at my disposal.

Any remarks would be appreciated.

Comment: $\hat{d}(0,\lim s_n)=\lim\hat{d}(0,s_n)$ because of continuity property of a metric.

Comment: You should explain, what is given and what we want to construct.

Comment: @user10354138 thank you. You mean that for any vector space that has a metric, the map $+: X \times X \to X$ is a continuous mapping of metric spaces?

Comment: No,  I am only using $[y_n]+[z_n]$ represents $[y_n+z_n]$, not the continuity of addition on $\hat{X}$ that we are trying to establish with this proof of triangle inequality.  Using that and the continuity of $\hat{d}\colon\hat{X}\times\hat{X}\to\mathbb{R}$ you get (?).

Comment: Ok. could you explain why all of $d^$ must be continuous? Also, why does that imply the limit you said at first?

Comment: @user10354138 Also, I guess your line of reasoning assumes that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \hat{y}^{(1)}_n + \hat{y}^{(2)}_n = \hat{x}_1 + \hat{x}_2$. Why would this be true then? I’ve tried proving this with not much progress at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that elements of $\hat{X}$ are equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences in $X$, with the equivalence relation $[x] \sim [y]$ iff $x_n - y_n \to 0$, i.e $\lim_{n \to \infty}\|x_n - y_n\| = 0$. The norm on $\hat{X}$ is defined as $\|[x]\| = \lim_{n \to \infty}\|x_n\|$, and is well defined since $(\|x_n\|)$ is a cauchy sequence of real numbers and $x \sim y$ implies $\lim_{n \to \infty}\|x_n\| = \lim_{n \to \infty}\|y_n\|$.

The triangle inequality is proved by applying the definition of $\|\|$ and $+$ on $\hat{X}$:
\begin{align}
\|[x] + [y]\| &= \|[x + y]\| \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\|x_n + y_n\| \\
&\leq \lim_{n \to \infty}(\|x_n\| + \|y_n\|) \\
&= \|[x]\| + \|[y]\|.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer.